# Tapestry5 creating complex component element id issue

Tags: tapestry

I want to make complex component using existing ones with addition of static html. Something like

```
<div class="form-item" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <label for="form-item-label">Opis</label>
    <t:textfield class="data" t:id="clientId" t:value="value" />
</div>
```

And I want to set textfield's id to parameterized value clientId, not to fixed "clientId" value.

Java part of component is:

```
public class FormItemTextField {
    @Parameter(required = true, name = "value", defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.PROP)
    private String value;
    @Parameter(required = true, name = "clientid", defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.LITERAL)
    private String clientId;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the DOM id in your tml and set it to whatever you'd like it to be.

```
<div class="form-item" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <label for="form-item-label">Opis</label>
    <t:textfield class="data" t:id="clientId" id="${myCoolId}" t:value="value" />
</div>
```

With your java like:

```
public class FormItemTextField {
    @Parameter(required = true, name = "value", defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.PROP)
    private String value;
    @Parameter(required = true, name = "clientid", defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.LITERAL)
    private String clientId;

    ...

    public String getMyCoolId() {
        return "anythingYouWant";
    }

}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and I got this HTML
`<div class="form-item">
    <label for="form-item-label">Opis</label>
    <input class="data" id="clientId" name="clientId" type="text">
    <img id="clientId_icon" class="t-error-icon" alt="" src="/granny/assets/1.0-SNAPSHOT/core/spacer.gif" style="display: none;">
</div>`
So, it's not the HTML I wanted...

Comment: Than it is not clear from your question what the HTML is that you want.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your time and quick response. I'll try to explain what I want. I want to use this code in my tml file `<t:FormItemTextField t:clientId="some_id" value="myObject.myField" label="MyLabel"/>` and clientId should be variable, not constant, so I could reuse this component. In this case, HTML would be `... <input class="data" id="some_id" name="some_id" type="text"> ...` (fine HTML code is replaced with "...")